# Error while executing javascript program

Tags: javascript, html

I got an error while executing the following program.I tried to execute the program in head first javascript text book. Please help. Error:Uncaught TypeError: blog[i].containsText is not a function.

### Program:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function Blog(body,date)
            {
                 this.body=body;
                 this.date=date;
            }
            var blog=[new Blog("Got the new cube I ordered...","08/14/2008"),
                        new Blog("Solved the new cube of course...","08/19/2008"),
                         new Blog("Managed to get a headache to iling...","08/14/2008"),
                         new Blog("Found a 7X7X7 cube for sale online..","08/14/2008")];

        function showBlog(numEntries)
        {
                 if(!numEntries)
                        numEntries=blog.length;
                var i=0, blogText="";
                while(i<blog.length&&i<numEntries)
                {
                     if(i%2==0)
                        blogText+="<p style='background-color:#EEEEEE'>";
                    else
                         blogText+="<p>";

                   // alert(blog[i].date+" "+blog[i].body);

                    blogText+="<strong>"+blog[i].date+"</strong><br/>"+blog[i].body+"</p>";
                    i++;
                    //alert(blogText);
                }
                var blogDate=new Date("08/14/2008");
                alert(blogDate.toString());                 
                // document.getElementById('pi').innerText.containsText;
                var searchText=document.getElementById('pi').value;
                for(var i=0;i<blog.length;i++)
                {
                    if(blog[i].containsText(searchText))
                    {

                        alert(blog[i]);
                    }
                }
                 document.getElementById('blog').innerHTML=blogText;
        }

        this.containsText=function(text)
        {
            alert(this.body.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()));
        };
        </script>

        </head>    


            <body onload="showBlog(5);">
  <h3> YouCube- The Blog for cube puzzlers</h3>
  <img src="img/Cube-with-blender.png" alt="YouCube"/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>  
  <div id="blog"></div>
  <p id="pi">Got the new cube I ordered</p>
  <input type="button" id="showall" value="show all blog entries" onclick="showBlog();"/>
        </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Blog constructor does not have containsText function.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `this` within the global scope, when you do this.containsText = fn. This means that containsText function is attached to the window object. You should do it within the Blog constructor if you want this method to be available to all instances of Blog constructor.

Try this.

```
function Blog(body,date)
        {
             this.body=body;
             this.date=date;
              this.containsText = function(str){
              if(this.body.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase())>=0){
                       return true;
                    }
                   return false;
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
this.containsText=function(text){
         alert(this.body.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()));
 };
```

use,

```
Blog.prototype.containsText=function(text)
        {
            alert(this.body.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()));
        };
```

Because u have to attach containsText method to the prototype of the Blog constructor.